# Timeago and jQuery dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, timeago

Using datatables and timeago. Some dates are not showing on next pages when I click on the next page. But with this code it solved it.

```
$("#simpledatatable_paginate").click(function(){
    jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
```

However, when I clicked on table headings `sort` or the show pages `10, 20, 25, 50, 100 etc` and also `search` in datatables some data the data is not displayed. Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take advantage of the `draw.dt` event. It is called every time the dataTables instance is redrawn, i.e when sorting, filtering, changing page etc. Create the handler *before* you initialize the dataTable (I assume  your table id is `#simpledatatable`) :

```js
$("#simpledatatable").on('draw.dt', function() {
   jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});

$("#simpledatatable").DataTable({
   ...
});
```

Now you can skip any other `timeago()` calls. The problem is that `jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();` only targets present or visible `abbr.timeago` elements, not those who are injected later on when you are sorting, changing page etc.

Comment: Thank you, this works but is very slow :( - there is a few second delay going to the next page in datatables with the above. Any solution that is faster?